# Android/iOS app: Is there a way to store a unique user identifier that is tied to the users fingerprint?

Tags: android, iphone

What I want to be able to do is create an app that users can login in to with their fingerprint. But not just on their device any device running the app would need the ability to recognise who the user is from their fingerprint. I realise the users fingerprint is stored on their own device only and doesn't get exposed to anything outside of their device so is this possible at all? Is there a way that I could store something in the cloud that would be able to identify who a user is from their fingerprint?

Comment: without using a third party scanning library, probably not

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. The fingerprint is saved in a seccure place by android/ios and you CAN'T access it. You eighter can't asing a UUID or something unique like this to it because the only method you are able to use in relation to the fingerprint of an user is like a match method that returns a percentage of equality from your fingerprint compared with any fingerprint saved in the device.

Maybe this helps:

1. Android: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html
2. External library: http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm
3. External library: http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html